# SQL Server 2008 intellisense no longer working

Tags: sql-server-2008, intellisense

I installed SSMS Tools and now my intellisense isn't working.  Is there a reset settings, like for VS (devenv /resetsettings)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so after all the help from Barry, I had to repair the installation from the DVD and now I have intellisense back.  This worked for me, but Barry's may work for others.

Answer (score 6):

Check two things:

1 - is the Intellisense enabled under Tools > Options:

[image]

2 - does refreshihg the local cache help??

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response.  This was the first thing I tried, but still nothing.

Answer (score 1):

If you right click in a the query window there is an option to enable the Intellisense.

What about running

```
SSMS.EXE /selfreg /setup
```

in a command prompt

Comment: Will give it a try and let you know.

Comment: Also this post may be of some use http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173434.aspx

Comment: I have tried the SSMS.EXE command, but it still isn't working.  Is there anything else that I can try?

Comment: Have you looked at the link I posted?

Comment: Then I'm all out of ideas I'm afraid.  Only other option would be to reinstall the client tools.  You are connected to a SQL 2008 database aren't you?  Intellisense wont work on anything below SQL 2008.

Comment: Appreciate the help and ideas that you have given me.  I will try and repair the installation to see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and it turned out the machine was running out of disk space.  Added space, and the problem went away.